# Advice on using web-platform or MVC on a project described above

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

our team wants to develop a website. It's kind of a social network for education. We already have a MVP(first prototype).
We have 3 programmers who are kind of expert in .net webform, but only one of them knows about MVC. Our MVP is medium in features now and it's using three layered architecture based on .net webform. In future there might be more interest in it and we may have much more users and we'll sure need to add new features to it(and it also has a huge database!). We want to deliver our product in 3 months.
I want to ask, is it better to develop our web site based on MVC or not?

Comment: The problem with asking for "advice" is that all you are going to get is someone's opinion. This question is primarily opinion based (and therefore offtopic for StackOverflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to answer this for you. Only you can decide. Web Forms, while still pretty popular, I would say has a definite shelf-life. I see it going the way of the dinosaurs within the next few years, especially after the release of ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6. The power and flexibility you'll have with that will make Web Forms look like amateur hour. If you want to be future-safe, MVC is the way to go.

On the other hand, 2/3 of your developers have never touched MVC before and you want to release in 3 months. MVC is relatively easy to pick up, but to learn what you need for a large scale application, could easily take 3 months. If you *have* to release in 3 months, your only option is probably Web Forms.

Comment: Hi. I have one [question in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273517/best-practice-for-persisting-user-state-in-special-kind-of-asp-net-mvc-applicati). Could you please help me as it is very urgent. And I will really be helpful for your help.